# AgentTicketQueue to display locked tickets also by default?

Tags: otrs

We are two people coordinating the work of 14 first and second line support
employees. We would like to be able to dive into a specific queue like
"Printers" and see what is going on in there.

If we use the AgentTicketQueue view we get all the open tickets, but we
need to see the locked tickets too, to be able to see what our people are
currently working on and if anything needs to be reprioritized.

I know we can click the "All tickets" button when we have selected a queue,
and that does work. The problem is that queues with no unlocked tickets
will not be displayed at all in the AgentTicketQueue view. This is quite a
common occurence here because all tickets gets assigned (locked) quickly,
but can take time to solve and close.

There's also the AgentTicketStatusView but that includes tickets from all
queues in a jumble and is not very useful in our situation with 500+
tickets in progress.

Is there a setting or hack to enable this mode of operation? Ideally it
would be a separate menu item, because most agents will want the current
OTRS functionality to pick unlocked tickets from.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way ( without any additional coding or hacking ) is to use search filter templates.

Press on the looking glass icon (Search) on the top menu of OTRS.

Set up the Search filter (see the img). Set up needed queues, states and lock statuses.
Afterwards - save it as a template ( Create New ) and in case you want to quick view tickets from various queues - just make a template for every queue you want.

Of course there is a possibility to make a custom Dashboard widget, but it will require a few hours of development.

[image: Search filter]